# zend show label instead of text field

Tags: php, zend-framework

in form, there is text, which get values from DB, when DB is empty that time empty textbox will display,

now i want to show label(please update DB first) instead of blank textbox. how to do this in form.

```
$txt_box = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('txt_ur_randID');

$this->addElements(array($username,$txt_box,$submit));
```

Comment: I'd use a [`placeholder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Input#placeholder).  Alternately, use conditional logic and set a style on the text element and use CSS to make it look like a label.

Answer (score 0):

i just done with Zend_Form_Element_Note class.